# cloudkit_js saveRecord error handling

Tags: java, error-handling, cloudkit

In cloudkit_js the error handling for saveRecord is not working for me. Here is a small example:

```
            var location = {
                        latitude: self.newCameraLatitude(),
                        longitude: self.newCameraLongitude()
            };

            var record = {
                recordType: "The Thing",
                fields: {
                    title: { value: self.newThingTitle() },
                    location: { value: location },
                }
            };

            privateDB.saveRecord(record).then(
                function(response) {
                    if (response.hasErrors) {
                        console.log('Might need to call Huston');
                        console.error(response.errors[0]);
                    } else {
                     // do something
                    }
                });
```

The code does save records to the private database if the input parameters are OK.
When a Lat/lng has values that are out of bounds an error occurs during the save. That error is not trapped by if (response.hasErrors).

Here's the error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

And when I click on it in the Web Inspector console I get this:

```
{
    "uuid": "a7d41349-b9f0-499c-9d30-43b7c23e6355",
    "serverErrorCode": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "reason": "invalid attempt to use latitude outside valid range of -90.0 to 90.0"
}
```

So... I understand the error - that's not the issue.
The issue is that I want to trap the error and handle it with the user but 'if (response.hasErrors)' doesn't seem to trap it.

Any ideas?

- David

Answer (score 0):

And this is how I trapped the error and handled it...

```
            privateDB.saveRecords(record)
            .then(function(response) {
                    if (response.hasErrors) {
                        throw response.errors[0];
                    } else {
                     // do something
                    }
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                      console.log('Gota catch em all -->'+error);
                      // handle the jandle! :-)
                      self.saveButtonEnabled(true);
                });
```

The .catch receives the "error" - this is a CKError and looks like this:

```
[CKError
ckErrorCode: BAD_REQUEST
extensionErrorCode: undefined
isError: true
isServerError: true
isServerExtensionError: true
message: invalid attempt to use longitude outside valid range of -180.0 to 180.0
name: Error
reason: invalid attempt to use longitude outside valid range of -180.0 to 180.0
recordName: undefined
redirectURL: undefined
retryAfter: undefined
serverErrorCode: BAD_REQUEST
subscriptionID: undefined
uuid: 6feaa17b-8bc2-4b98-a1d2-3a0ac5bbb4da
zoneID: undefined
]
```

- David